# Is there a way to open several connections through script on Anydesk?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, powershell, cmd.exe

I'm trying to make a script where I could do the following:

1. Open an Anydesk connection
2. Put the ID and password
3. Close the connection
4. Repeat 1, 2 and 3 but with different IDs.

The idea of this is because I have a lot of computers where I have to configure several IDs with its respective password. So I'd like to save time and not doing manually.

This is what I tried:

```
echo <password> | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" <ID/Alias> --with-password
echo <password> | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" <ID/Alias> --with-password
```

The first connection works, but it doesn't go through the next connection, unless I manually close the program, if I do that, it does go to the next line of the script. I don't know if there's a way to close it automatically so it could run one line after another immediately.

I'd gladly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start` to launch separate cmd instances, and add the anydesk .exe location to your PATH (or figure out how to properly escape quotes):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk
start /min cmd /c "echo <password> | AnyDesk <ID/Alias> --with-password"
start /min cmd /c "echo <password> | AnyDesk <ID/Alias> --with-password"
```

Depending on the program, it will open a new (minimized) console window for each connection until you close that anydesk instance

---

Note that starting cmd this way will show the password in that process's command line info (can see it in task manager and some other places). A slightly improved example is using `type` to read the password from a file:

```
start /min cmd /c "type c:\users\username\creds.txt | AnyDesk.exe <ID/Alias> --with-password"
```

I also recommend not storing the passwords for your script in a plaintext batch file, but I'm not really familiar with what options anydesk allows.

Comment: Thanks! I have a little question though, how does the txt should look like? Because I tried it, but it's like it doesn't go through every password on the txt. 

Also, I just noticed it that when I login on a PC, I need to manually tick an option that saves the password. Is there a way to automate that? Cause I don't see any of those options on the Anydesk doc.

Comment: @Dany the txt should only have a single password (and a blank newline I think). Use separate files for different passwords. I would guess you just need to manually connect with the password once to remember it, and then maybe you can skip using `--with-password` after? I'm not sure

Comment: If I use the script, it connects immedately but it doesn't remember it. To remember it, I'd have to connect manually, which is what I'd like to avoid. Because I want to open all those connections one after another to leave the passwords already saved. Maybe I'd have to use other commands or try with Powershell to try to simulate ticking the option to remember the passwords? Because I don't see any option regarding that here: https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/command-line-interface-for-windows

Comment: @Dany maybe just use the commands to open connections, and/or save as separate bat files to run? Opening them manually shouldn't be too bad since you only have to do it once, right? Otherwise, you might be better off with something like autohotkey scripts to open each connection prompt, type in the pw, click remember, and so on